# How can I read an excell csv file with colored cells into a tabular or table and display the color formatting?

Tags: tables, color, csv

This is my code for reading the csv files into a tabular, but it does not keep the color formatting:

```
\csvreader[tabular={|c|c|r|c|c|c|c|c|c|},
before reading = \begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth},
    after reading=\end{adjustbox},
    table head=\hline \textbf{WT} & \textbf{Beam} & \textbf{Threshold} &\textbf{500m} &\textbf{1000m} &\textbf{1500m}&\textbf{2000m}&\textbf{3000m} &\textbf{4000m}\\\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline]%
{StHubert/RCS30.csv}{WTname=\wt, Beam=\b, Threshold=\thres, 500=\v,1000=\d, 1500=\dv, 2000=\t, 3000=\tv, 4000=\dr}
{\wt & \b & \thres[dBw] &\v & \d &\dv &\t &\tv&\dr}
```

As an example I have added an image of the csv file with the filled cells.

[image: CSV file with filled cells]

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to present complete code only, not just a fragment. I.e. just copy and compile your posted code in your environment. If it doesen't compile, please add the necessary missing parts and change your posted code here. It may also help to make a short version of your Excel file available somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Note that a CSV in its basic nature does not contain infomation about cell color (it is a text only format). What exactly does that CSV look like?